# Toggling between different overlay (Google Map)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have added the whole chunk of my coding here. They might look similar to you guys its because i have build the project base on the [earthquake visualization tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/visualizing/earthquakes). The tutorial was really good but as for now, i am trying to get either a button or a check box to toggle between the different overlay.

I have split my code into 4 parts. The heating, the marker, the circle and the heat-map. Would really appericate if someone could help me out as i did tried many tutorial or examples outside but it wasn't very successful.

This is my code

heading

```
<script>
    var map;
    var results;

    //setting up map
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.48939, 153.012772),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
          };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);

      //set location of file
      var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.src = '\week.json';
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); 
    }



 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    //createMarker function
    function createMarker(latLng, title, content,icon) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latLng,
              map: map,
              title: title,
            });


    //click or moveover listener for infowindow
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

    }
```

Info window with markers

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

function createMarker(latLng, title, content,icon) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          map: map,
          title: title,
        });

    window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
      var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {

        var wifin = results.features[i]; 
        var coords = wifin.geometry.coordinates; 
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]); 
        bounds.extend(latLng);

        var content ="<div style='height:100px; width:300px; overflow:auto;'><table>";
        content += "<tr><th align='left'>WifiMacAddress</th><td>"+wifin.properties.WifiMacAddress+"</td></tr>";
        content += "<tr><th align='left'>SSID</th><td>"+wifin.properties.SSID+"</td></tr>";
        content += "<tr><th align='left'>SignalStrength</th><td>"+wifin.properties.SignalStrength+"</td></tr>";
        content += "<tr><th align='left'>WifiFrequency</th><td>"+wifin.properties.WifiFrequency+"</td></tr>";
        content +="</table>";

        createMarker(latLng,wifin.WifiMacAddress,content);
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

circle size

```
window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
     var wifin = results.features[i]; 
        var coords = wifin.geometry.coordinates; 
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]); 
        //bounds.extend(latLng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      icon: getCircle(wifin.properties.SignalStrength)
    });
  }
}

function getCircle(strength) {
  return {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: 'green',
    fillOpacity: .2,
    scale: Math.pow(2, strength) / Math.PI,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: .5
  };
}
```

heatmap

```
window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
var heatmapData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
     var wifin = results.features[i]; 
        var coords = wifin.geometry.coordinates; 
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]); 
        var magnitude = wifin.properties.SignalStrength;
    var weightedLoc = {
      location: latLng,
      weight: Math.pow(2, magnitude)
    };
    heatmapData.push(weightedLoc);
  }
     var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      //position: latLng,
      data: heatmapData,
      dissipating: false,
      map: map
    });
  }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says: `results` is not defined. Specifically, since your `onclick` inline event handler is executed in the global scope, `results` must be a global variable. Have you defined a global variable `results`?

Comment: You are right. I did not declare a global variable for the result as the tutorial guide i was following did not add one. 

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/visualizing/earthquakes)

Comment: Do you have any recommendation as to how else can i do a toggle function ? to hid and un-hid the overlay ?

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like?  Can't help you without knowing what "results" is supposed to be.  Do you have a fiddle that exhibits the problem?  Or a link to a live map?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to offer specific suggestions without seeing the rest of your code, but here are some general questions and thoughts: Your current `onclick` code requires `results` to be a global variable. How is `results` defined now, if at all? In general it would be better to use a jQuery event handler instead of an inline event handler. For example give your `<button>` an `id="toggler"` and then in your code (not in `onclick`) use `$('#toggler').on( 'click', function() { toggleHeatmap(results); });`. But this requires `results` to be in scope wherever that code is. So what is `results`?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help. I have uploaded the whole code, basically the function for the heatmap is working fine just that i am having problem with toggling the overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This toggles the heatmap in the [Google Earthquake example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/tutorials/visualizing/js/earthquake_heatmap) (if I make the "heatmap" variable global as well as the map)

```
<input type="button" id="toggle" value="toggle layer" onclick="if (heatmap.getMap() == null) {heatmap.setMap(map) } else {heatmap.setMap(null)}"></input>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_earthquakeHeatmap_toggle.html)

Comment: Cheers mate. That is exactly what i am looking for. Dose it work the same way for the standard marker as well as the circle function ? I tried doing the same way you did the toggle, however it doesnt work. It works for either one both not both together.

Comment: That wasn't part of your original question.  The same concept will work for all the various options.

Comment: Hi @geocodeZip, Yes that wasn't part of my original question. I have made some changes to my question so that i wont have to create a new thread. I have successfully did what you have shared with me on the other layers. However they are only able to work in a separate file and not together under the same script. Do you have any idea what might have gone wrong ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Display all three layers and allow them to be toggled with buttons?  Checkboxes?  Have radio buttons to allow one (or none) of the three to be selected? A dropdown/select list?

Comment: Hi @geocodezip, i am actually trying to allow the user an option to switch between the 3 layers. -Cheers

Comment: The question was _how_ did you want to give them that option.

Comment: My bad, i misread your previous message. A normal button would suffice. I am thinking 3 buttons to allow user to toggle between the layers. @geocodezip

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clear-all-overlays/clear-all-overlays.html) (found in the [demo gallery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery) with a search for "clearing overlays")

Comment: Hey @geocodezip, this is my first time seeing that. I will try to work mine base on that and will let you know again if its successful . Thanks